# flexbox parent is having trouble with children elements

Tags: html, css, flexbox

the parent div, .blog_content, has two childern, one is a p element and the other is an image. for some reason they are behaving like block objects and not inline block. what is happenning is they are appearing on top of each other, like block elements would and not beside each other like what im trying to accomplish. i have set widths for them but they seem to be just ignoring them.

ill post the code below.

the relevant html
edit to show the full code

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My blog</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css"> 
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav>
            <div id="nav_links">
                <a href="#">Home</a>
                <a href="#">all posts</a>
                <a href="#">Services</a>
                <a href="#">About</a>
                <a href="#">Contact</a>
            </div>
            <div id="nav_search">
                <form method="post" action="#">
                    <input id="nav_form_input" type="text" name="nav_search" placeholder="Search">
                    <input id="nav_search_submit" type="submit" value="GO">
                </form> 
            </div>
        </nav>
<main>
    <section>
        <article>
                <h1>My first blog post</h1>
                <hr>
                <div class="blog_content">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborumLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. </p>
                    <img src="images/159.jpg" alt="shit hot 159">
                </div>
            </article>
         </section>
        <aside>
        </aside>
    </main>
  </body>
</html>
```

the relevant css

```
/* -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* START OF HEADER.HTML STYLES */
/* -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/


nav {
    position: relative;
    height: 40px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgb(40,50,60);
}

#nav_links {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    padding-left: 40px;
    height: 40px;   

    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: center;
}

#nav_search {
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    padding-right: 80px;
    height: 40px;

    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    align-items: center;
}

nav > #nav_links > a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: rgb(220,220,220);
    padding-left: 25px;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px grey;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}

#nav_form_input{
    border-radius: 10px 0px 0px 10px;
    height: 20px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    color: rgb(220,220,220);
    background-color: rgb(60,70,80);
    padding: 5px;
}

#nav_search_submit {
    border-radius: 5px;
    height: 30px;
    border: 1px solid rgb(60,110,30);
    background: linear-gradient(rgb(100,160,80), rgb(90,140,60));
    font-family: arial;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: rgb(240,240,240);
}

/* -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* START OF MAIN.HTML STYLES */
/* -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

main {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: nowrap ;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 600px;

    flex-flow: row nowrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: flex-start;
}

main section {
    margin: 20px auto;
    width: 65%;
    min-height: 400px;
}

main section article {
    border-radius: 30px 30px 0px 0px;
    background-color: rgb(240,240,240);
    height: 400px;
}


main section article h1 {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 10px 0px 10px 20px;
    border-radius: 30px 20px 0px 0px;
    border: 2px 2px 0px 2px solid rgb(0,0,255);
    color: white;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    background: linear-gradient(rgb(80,170,240), rgb(60,140,240));
    font-weight: 400;
}

hr {
    width: 95%;
    color: rgb(120,120,120);
}

.blog_content {
    display: inline-flex;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 100%;
}


main section article p {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: wrap;  
    width: 42%;
}

main section article img {
    margin: 3%;
    width: 42%;

    border-radius: 4px;
}

main aside {
    margin: 20px auto;
    width: 20%;
    min-height: 400px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

i have tried using both flex and inline-flex but no joy with either

Comment: How would you expect them to behave ?

Comment: sorry i forgot about that part. i need to have them side by side, not on top of each other

Comment: Seems to [work](https://jsfiddle.net/35youkp6/) ?

Comment: ill edit to post the full code. i will leave out normalize.css its too long

Comment: this is very weird, i put all of it into jsfiddle and it works fine. i cleared my browsing data and still nothing. anyone have any ideas?

Comment: You probably have a weird syntax error in your local copy.